# How to migrate data from google cloud mysql to cloud spanner using dataflow

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-dataflow, google-cloud-spanner

is there a tutorial that shows how to do this? I was reading a little bit and I think one way would be to send the data from mysql to bigquery, then from bigquery to spanner, but is there another way easier? or is there any tutorial? Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can try this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/spanner/docs/migrating-mysql-to-spanner#migration-process) steps stated are:

> 1. Convert your schema and data model.
> 2. Translate any SQL queries.
> 3. Migrate your application to use Spanner in addition to MySQL.
> 4. Bulk export your data from MySQL and import your data into Spanner using Dataflow.
> 5. Maintain consistency between both databases during your migration.
> 6. Migrate your application away from MySQL.

Above are listed overall steps, for more details about them you visit the documentation linked above.

Comment: There's also a Spanner migration tool that supports MySQL to Spanner migrations. See https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/spanner-migration-tool